# Does Kotlin guarantee that a range check doesn't instantiate a Range?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my Android app, I wrote

```
return x >= rangeStart && x <= rangeEnd
```

IntelliJ has an inspection that wants me to change this to

```
return x in rangeStart..rangeEnd
```

however, since this code is on the critical path of high-volume event handling, I can accept the transformation only if I know for sure that the second form won't create any garbage. Is there such a guarantee in Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the bytecode generated by the Kotlin compiler yourself by searching actions and typing in "Show Kotlin Bytecode", or from the menu via Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode.

Optimizing range checks on primitives (Int, Double, etc) is a pretty trivial thing to do, so you'll find that the Kotlin compiler always does the optimization for you with these types. If you have just a few of these on your critical code path, you can check that it happens by hand to feel safe about using ranges.

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) is brief about this, but it does say:

> Range is defined for any comparable type, but for integral primitive types it has an optimized implementation.

Comment: I hate to code against implementation details, but i guess that sentence, and the comment in the code example, combined with what I saw in the bytecode, put my worries at rest.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a very safe bet, the optimization is basically promised by the docs. It's not an optimization that would disappear from the compiler with newer version or anything.

Comment: I just noticed the docs say "for _integral_ primitive types", whereas I deal with Floats :) But the optimization is still there.

Comment: It's "integral" as in essential or basic, not as in integer :)

Comment: No, that word actually has a specified sense. See [Kotlin spec](http://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_miscellaneous) and [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1).

Comment: Oh, I see, that's quite interesting. I still think the Kotlin docs might not be using it in the sense that the specs are.

Comment: I think it's an erratum because the very next sentence uses it correctly: "Integral type ranges (`IntRange`, `LongRange`, `CharRange`) have an extra feature:  they can be iterated over". `FloatRange` cannot be iterated over. Taken as written, the docs give no guarantee for the optimization of the `FloatRange`.

Comment: *I hate to code against implementation details* - @MarkoTopolnik I guess it's fair to say that you can code for intent without thinking about the implementation details of the range checks. Then when you go out of your way to optimize a hot code path like here, you're almost by definition looking at implementation details.

Comment: @joffrey There's another argument, one that for example spurred a lot of controversy around the usage of enums vs. raw ints in core Java APIs -- if you aspire to replace an established idiom with a new one, it must not introduce surprising changes to performance. If I'm supposed to blindly use `in a..b` instead of bounds checks -- and this is a very typical idiom in hot loops -- it should better not hold any nasty surprises for me. In Effective Java, Josh Bloch gave the advice to always use enums where we used ints so far -- and Doug Lea passionately disagreed. Streams API uses int constants.

Answer (score 2):

Example from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)

```
if (i in 1..10) { // equivalent of 1 <= i && i <= 10
    println(i)
}
```

I think it's language "Sugar" and it's equals!